# Utilizing Google Home or Alexa's TTS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to build an end point for Google Home or Alexa so I can process the text within the application and spit out a response for either devices to use its text to speech.

I looked over [Google's Actions SDK](https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/sdk/) and setup the example project, but I'm a little confused on what the purpose of using Google's cloud platform is. Is the cloud platform what processes a user's voice into text, or does the Google Home do that?

Comment: I know Alexa processes it in the cloud and I doubt if Google do anything different. Amazon use their Lambda platform, which is optimised for one-off tasks

Comment: @MatthewDaly Ah. Alexa requires a 'trigger' in order to start listening. Can this be avoided -- or at least programatically listen after saying something -- with Google Actions?

Comment: @MatthewDaly Nevermind, I guess that's the purpose of a Conversation. https://developers.google.com/actions/design/walkthrough

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to bypass this, but it can pick out parts of what you say and pass it through. Lambda is basically just a function that gets called with whatever arguments you pass through so you could theoretically pass through whatever you need. [The documentation on writing skills for Alexa](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/overviews/understanding-custom-skills) may be useful, and it's possible to run Alexa on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A voice application usually consists of several elements:

- **audio input** through a voice-enabled device
- **speech recognition**, done by voice platforms like Alexa or Google Actions
- **natural language understanding**, to make sense of the text
- **code**, which uses the data provided by the NLU and returns a text to respond to the users

For your specific question regarding Google Actions, the Actions on Google Platform does the **Speech Recognition**, and usually, the **Natural Language Understanding** part of Google Actions is done by [Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/).

When you're using the Actions on Google SDK, the Google Cloud Platform is used to host the **Code** of your app. You can also just parse the JSON yourself if you want to host it somewhere else, or use a framework like [Jovo](https://www.jovo.tech/), which allows you to host voice applications on your own server or on AWS Lambda. Here's a simple tutorial for Google Actions: https://www.jovo.tech/blog/google-action-tutorial-nodejs/

If you're really just interested in using the text to speech output, you might also look at other ways, e.g. you could use [Amazon Polly](https://aws.amazon.com/polly/), a service that allows you to do TTS either programmatically or manually, although it doesn't offer the Alexa voice right now.